# Reduce the compact domain of onto continuous function and it is still onto

Tags: general-topology

I found the question in Willard and it seems interesting to me because it shows that we can reduce the domain and still have onto.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces and let $f$ be a continuous function of $X$ onto $Y$. Then there exists a compact subset $X_0$ of $X$ such that $f[X_0]=Y$, but $f$ maps no proper closed subset of $X_0$ onto $Y$.

**My uncomplete attempt**: The hint says Zorn's lemma. I was trying to start by set $$\mathcal F=\{A\subset X\colon \ \ A \ \ \text{compact} \ \& \ f[A]=Y\}$$ and shows every nonempty chain has upper bound. So, I can use Zorn's lemma. But I realized that $\mathcal F$ already has maximal element, which is $X$.  Any idea will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Maybe order $\mathcal F$ by inverse inclusion, so $A\leqslant B$ if $A\supseteq B$

Comment: @Alessandro, thank you. But why $\mathcal F\neq \emptyset.$

Comment: You can't "reduce the domain and still have homeomomorphism", but $f$ is not claimed to be a homeomorphism anyway.

Comment: @DavidHartley, Maybe you are right. I think I should not write homeomomrphism

Comment: $\mathcal{F}\ne \emptyset$ because $X\in \mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  the poset $$\mathcal{F}= \{A \subseteq X\mid A \text{ closed in } X \land f[A]=Y\}$$ ordered by **reverse** inclusion. This poset is non-empty as $X$ is in it.

So $A \le B$ for $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ iff $B \subseteq A$.

Then if $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a chain, use $C_0:=\bigcap \mathcal{C}$ as an upperbound. The "challenge" is to show that $C_0 \in \bigcap{F}$ so $f[C_0]=Y$.

The restricted map (to the maximal element $X_0$) is called *irreducible* BTW and need not be 1-1 or a homeomorphism.

Comment: I think I have the right post. what did you mean by $\bigcap F$

Comment: $\bigcap \mathcal C$ is the intersection of all members of $\mathcal C$ of course @00GB. I did not write $\bigcap \mathcal F$. Maybe that set is empty. That's the poinrt of using Zorn to give  you a maximal (for $\le$) element, which is $\subseteq$-minimal..

Comment: Thank you for your help as usual. I think I should be able to finish. Need to show to things 1. $C_0$ is closed and 2. $f[C_0]=Y $

Comment: @00GB The intersection of closed sets is always closed. No work there.

Comment: I meant nonempty since $X$ is compact

Comment: @00GB It is non-empty by nestedness (chain!) and compactness yes. Now show $C_0$ still maps onto $Y$.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, I was able to finish the proof completely based in your hint.

Comment: @00GB that’s nice to hear.